# iOS: "Report a Bug" button ok?

Tags: ios

This question has less to do with programming and more to do with the Apple Review process.

I would like to have a "Report a Bug" button in the settings screen of my app, where users can do just that. Then when they hit submit the report is sent to our server via email.

I don't think I've read anything in the guidelines about this kind of feature, but for some reason I'm worried the app might not get approved as this may indicate that our app is incomplete or riddled with bugs, which is not the case.

Has anyone implemented such a feature or has seen another application with such a feature? It could be really useful to devs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Apple review process

Comment: Try calling it "Submit Feedback" instead.

Comment: I always put a "Feedback" button in every app that opens a mail composer. Never been rejected for that. That way people can tell me how much they love the app or report a problem.

Comment: +1 for Feedback button with mail composer. This also is good for stopping people giving negative feedback in Appstore reviews. I have not got issues neither with mail composer "Report bug" nor with native view with feedback submission form

Comment: @MikeW and other close voters. I would say this is on topic since it falls under `practical, answerable problems that are unique to software development`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this could be a reason for rejection. If it happens anyway you can just argue with them or change the "Report a Bug" to "Give us your feedback". But anyway they won't reject you app because of this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually thought of having a feedback instead of a bug button as well and I may have to go that route. But ideally, as good as it feels to have someone send you good feedback, we would like to have feedback we can work with. Either way, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've this feature implemented in many apps. Just change the language to 'Feedback' (vs Report a Bug), and you should be fine.